# Failed to load PDF Document in Chrome only

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I have implemented file download functionality such that if file can directly be open up in browser like PDF file then open in the browser otherwise download file. I have implemented file download service which returns data in the byte[] array.

**When I am open PDF file directly in the browser, only first time it gives error as per the screenshot attached. In all attempts afterwards open file successfully.** Also, issue is re-produced when I am close Chrome and re-open.[image]

I looked into console panel and it says "ERR_HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED". I am not sure what it means by that.